# Derive formula for area of elipse using the constant sum of distances to focuses

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry

I have an idea for a derivation of the formula for the area of the elipse, but don't know how to formalize it, or if it even can be formalized.

With a bit (a ton) of handwaving, we can get the area by going around the elipse, and for every point on it, add the distance from that point to one focus. There's some correction that needs to be applied due to polar coordinates but I'll ignore it for now. So the formula would be something like

$$A=\int_E dist(x, f_1)dx$$

The same can be done for any point in the elipse, including the other focus, so

$$A=\int_E dist(x, f_2)dx$$

And now finally, I want to be able to do this magic:

$$2A=\int_E dist(x, f_1)dx + \int_E dist(x, f_2)dx=\int_E dist(x, f_1) + dist(x, f_2)dx=\int_E Cdx$$

where C is the constant that is the sum from the focuses to a point on the elipse. This should be easier to solve.

Is there any way to formalize this? Basically what I'm looking for is a derivation for the formula that uses a trick that's as similar as posible to what I improvized here.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the polar integral for area, the distance term is squared :(

Comment: Yes, recall that in integrating about a point $dA$ is not a rectangle, but a sector of a circle. That has to be taken into account.

Comment: What is $dx$ supposed to represent? An increment of distance along the circumference of the ellipse? If so, there's a (non-constant) correction factor you're ignoring having to do with angles. Also, the distance you're integrating over is the length of the circumference of the ellipse, which is much, much harder to compute than the area is.